# Trying to print paths of images linked with an incremented variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, kivy

I have method of randomizing all images in a directory to be listed with their path and outputted to a grid. I have a .kv file with id: from a - l and want to update my "a" variable after each time the path of an image is listed so that it is written to the self.ids.a.source = rand_img and then list the next path with the updated increment.

```
for f in files:
    f = random.choice([
            x for x in os.listdir(path)
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
            ])
        rand_img = ("kv\\animals\\" + str(f))
        print(rand_img)
        a = "`"
        while a != "e":
            a = chr(ord(a)+1)
            print(a)
            self.ids.a.source = rand_img
```

Currently the only the first path is shown and then the "a" variable is incremented until it is completed then the rest of the paths are shown.
What is printed:

```
kv\animals\cow.jpg
a
b
c
d
e
kv\animals\fish.jpg
kv\animals\camel.jpg
kv\animals\chicken.jpg
kv\animals\fish.jpg
```

What I am trying to get:

```
kv\animals\cow.jpg
a
kv\animals\fish.jpg
b
kv\animals\camel.jpg
c
kv\animals\chicken.jpg
d
kv\animals\fish.jpg
e
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` when you need to access the current index of a collection:

```
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    f = random.choice(
        [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))]
    )
    rand_img = "kv\\animals\\" + str(f)
    print(rand_img)
    a = chr(ord("`") + 1 + i)
    print(a)
    self.ids.a.source = rand_img
    ## or the following, not sure if you want that
    # getattr(self.ids, a).source = rand_img
```

Comment: When I replace the last line with `getattr(self.ids, a).source = rand_img` the only the final image is displayed. It's path is linked in the correct variable. Is there a way to save that last line and write it before moving on so that all images are displayed?

Comment: That's, I believe, another problem you have, uncommented code from above will assign twelve "different" image paths to related twelve different variables `self.ids.a.source`, `self.ids.b.source`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` statement is being fully evaluated in the first loop; by the end of the first loop, `a` is already equal to 'e' so that `while` statement will be skipped in each following loop.

You don't really need the while statement. Assign the value to `a` outside of your loop and just add to that `a` variable each time you pass through the loop.

```
a='a'
for f in files:
    f = random.choice([
            x for x in os.listdir(path)
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
            ])
    rand_img = ("kv\\animals\\" + str(f))
    print(rand_img)
    print(a)
    self.ids.a.source = rand_img
    a = chr(ord(a)+1)
```